# Cannot export a BACPAC from SQL Azure -- ExtAuth_Key10 is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I'm getting an error with exporting the database that's housed in SQL Azure. The database itself is already v12. When I try to export the database, I get this error:

> The element ExtAuth_Key10 is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

I checked the related posts and saw that one recommendation was to update the DacFx framework. I've installed the latest I can find from Microsoft (16.5 at time of writing) as well as the SSMS (16.5.3 at time of writing). However I still get the same error.

It's very puzzling because this is an export operation, so it does not make sense to have something that is not supported in a V12 database in well, *a V12 database*.

What can be done to export this?

Answer (score 0):

What element is ExtAuth_Key10? is that a master key?

The latest version of SSDT bundled wtih DacFX is RC 3 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-release-candidate

Can you give that a try and let me know if you see any errors?